# Adding Text Information in Html Head

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

This could be something very simple, but I am having a hard time with this. I have to add some additional information into the heading information of a page. The issue is that the information always ends up in the body instead of heading.

**Here is the sample code**

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <text id="test">
        //Wish to add some additional information here
        tester
    </text>
    <title>Test Heading</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't add arbitrary text to [the `head` element in HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-head-element). There are only a few allowed tags (base, link, meta, noscript, script, style, template, title).

Comment: You can't have `<text />` in the head. If you have any information you can use `<script />` tags there and write your text in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Test Heading</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Latest sports news and live scores from Yahoo! Eurosport UK. Complete sport coverage with Football results, Cricket scores, F1, Golf, Rugby, Tennis and more.">
  <meta name="keywords" content="eurosport,sports,sport,sports news,live scores,football,cricket,f1,golf,rugby,tennis,uk,yahoo">


</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The customer is forcing the browser to behave like IE8; as a result, adding an xml tag in the heading works. Adding a line for IE8 compatibility did the trick for them.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8;" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <text id="students">
       <name>Name</name>
       <sCode>122</sCode>
    </text>
    <title>Test Heading</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```